# SQL to DAX with join and filtering by date

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

**how to create the code from SQL to DAX in Power BI as:**

```
Select
   History.[Key],
   History.[Issue Type],
   History.[Current Status],
   SUM(History.[Time in Old Value (business days)]) as 'Blocked Time'
FROM History
INNER JOIN CYCLOTIME
   ON HISTORY.[KEY] = CYCLOTIME.[KEY]
   AND HISTORY.[History Start] >= CycloTime.[Dt Inicio]
Where 
   History[History Field] = "flagged"
and
   History[History Old Value] = "Impedimento"
GROUP BY
   History.[Key],
   History.[Issue Type],
   History.[Current Status]
```

Someone could help me please?

Comment: What have you tried? Please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)